# SAML2 SSO Authenticator for Carbon 4.0 prooducts

Tags: single-sign-on, saml, wso2, wso2-esb

I need to use the SAML2 SSO Authenticator plugin for SSO in GREG 4.5.0, AS 5.0.0 and ESB 4.5.0 with IS 4.0 M9 or if it´s possible with v3.2.3.

What P2 repo can I use? I have an P2 repo offline, a zip file, for 4.0.0 version but I cannot find this plugin.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use 3.2.3 p2 repo with Carbon 4.0.0 based products ( Greg 4.50, ESB 4.5.0 etc.). IS features are not yet released. If you need to test the features you can get a [p2-repo](http://builder3.us1.wso2.org/builds/latest/p2-repo/) from this nightly build and try out them.

Edited:

As IS 4.0.0 is released you can download the p2-repo zip file from [here](http://dist.wso2.org/products/carbon/4.0.3/p2-repo.zip) or you can use online p2 repo from [here](http://dist.wso2.org/p2/carbon/releases/4.0.3/).

New IS release can be downloaded from [here](http://wso2.com/products/identity-server/).

Comment: Hi Shelan. can you provide a .zip repo URL with the lastest IS features?

Comment: Hi, I have added the links in the answer.